# Submit data to Flask without form

Tags: python, flask, post, datepicker

I have a datepicker always displayed, when I click I retrieve the date but I don't succeed to send it to my flask app.

HTML

```
 <div id="datepicker"></div>
```

JS

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
}).on("changeDate", function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
            var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
            //SUBMIT var date
        });
});
```

Python

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
.....

    if request.method == 'POST':
        date = date from datepicker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your file system for flask should look like so:

```
/ProjectName
  /Static
    MyJs.js
  /Templates
    index.html
  app.py
```

To return index.html, you have to run this in app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

It is very important that when doing this you have the right file structure. Finally, to send data from your JS files, all you need to do is send an AJAX request to a different route, that would be caught by your app.py file. This is how that would look:

app.py

```
@app.route('/date', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    Date = request.form['date']
```

```
$.ajax({
            data : {
                date : date
            },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/date'
        })
        .done(function(data) {

            if (data.error) {
                $('#errorAlert').text(data.error).show();
                $('#successAlert').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('#successAlert').text(data.name).show();
                $('#errorAlert').hide();
            }

        });
```

Comment: It works well. I retrieve the date in Date (process()) but when I want to return a template with return render_template('index.html', date=Date), nothing happends